# Mock componentDidMount lifecycle method for testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component which uses `axios` within `componentDidMount` to retrieve data from the server. When using Jest / Enzyme for unit testing the component, the tests fail with a network error.

How do I mock `componentDidMount` so that the `axios` call to the server does not happen?

The component in question uses [React DnD](http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-overview.html) and is a `DragDropContext`.

```
class Board extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.load_data();
    }

    load_data = () => {
        // axios server calls here
    }
}
export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(Board);
```

Example test:

```
it('should do something', () => {
    const board = shallow(<Board />);
    // get the boardInstance because board is wrapped in Reactdnd DragDropContext
    const boardInstance = board.dive().instance();
    boardInstance.callSomeMethodToTestIt();
    expect(testSomething);
}
```

So I just need to mock `componentDidMount` or `load_data` so that it doesn't try to call the server. If the `load_data` method was being passed in as a prop, I could simply set that prop to `jest.fn()`. However this is my top level component which does not receive any props.

Comment: What if you just reassign it via `board.instance().componentDidMount = jest.fn()`?

Comment: If you are using enzyme you can leverage `mount()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lifecyle methods do not defaultly work with shallow, you need to add a flag with shallow

```
 const board = shallow(<Board />, { lifecycleExperimental: true });
```

Before that you can create a spy on `componentDidMount` to check if it was called like

```
const spyCDM = jest.spyOn(Board.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
```

and to prevent the axios request from hitting the server , you can mock the axios call using **`moxios`**

Answer (score 7):

With the new update to enzyme, lifecycle methods are enabled by default. 
(https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3.html#lifecycle-methods)

However, you can disable them in with shallow rendering as such:

```
const board = shallow(<Board />, { disableLifecycleMethods: true });
```

docs: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html#shallownode-options--shallowwrapper